# Fragment not being removed properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some fragments i am trying to remove from my fragmentmanager. I use the following code to accomplish this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
for (String fragmentTag : fragmentsToRemove) {
    Fragment removedFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    if (removedFragment != null)
        transaction.remove(removedFragment);
}
transaction.commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

Later on, when i try to re-add a fragment i already deleted, i find it is still in the fragment manager:

```
            if (fm.findFragmentByTag(nextFragmentTag) == null) {
                mNextFragment = determineFragmentToSwitchTo(nextFragmentTag);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mNextFragment, nextFragmentTag);
            } else {
                transaction.show(mNextFragment);
            }

            transaction.addToBackStack(nextFragmentTag);            
            transaction.commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

The above code hits the above statement, the else is always called. What am idoing wrong

Comment: Do you add it to the  fragment to the backstack?

Comment: Yes i did. That logic is right under the selection statement

Comment: In that case removing the fragment using `remove` might not do it exactly as needed. you will probably need to pop it off the stack..

Comment: I just tried removing the addToBackStack line but it did not seem to have any effect...